# Table not getting created upon activation of WP Theme

Tags: table

This is the code I am using to create a custom table named "prefix" + zillow--> where prefix is the wp table prefix for the site.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'CreateTable');
```

The actual function is given below-- it checks if such a table already exists along with assigned version number for that table(so that I can update /alter that table in a later version of this theme)--

```
function CreateTable() {
  //Database table versions
  $zillow_db_table_version= "1.0";
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "zillow";

  $installed_ver = get_option( "zillow_db_table_version" );
  //Check if the table already exists and if the table is up to date, if not create it
  if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name || $installed_ver != $zillow_db_table_version ) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name .
    " (propertyid varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
    inserted_on date,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id) );";
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    update_option( "zillow_db_table_version", $zillow_db_table_version );
  }
  //Add database table versions to options
  add_option("zillow_db_table_version", $zillow_db_table_version);

}
```

But the table is not getting created at all. What is wrong with the above code?
I tried activating the theme using above code multiple times(after first activating a different theme and then activating this one) but no table is getting created (I check directly in the WP database list of tables ).

Comment: Have you tried adding `global $wpdb;` and turn on debugging.

Answer (score 1):

[`dbDelta` is extremely picky.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) Looking at your code I'd say you've violated this rule:

> You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement

Two of your fields are sharing lines with parenthesis. I haven't tested that particular pattern but `dbDelta` is *extremely* picky.

I don't know if that space after `NOT NULL` will matter.

I doubt that checking for the existence of the table is necessary. Checking your option should be sufficient.

And finally, [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) is for plugins, not themes. There is no similar specialized theme activation hook that I am aware of. There are a number of work-arounds that have been suggested if you search this site for them.

Comment: what do you suggest i use in place of dbDelta? Also the code sample in my question bunched up the code together-- actually in the php code the fields are all on different rows (including the key at the end of sql for table definition).

Comment: I don't suggest you use anything instead of `dbDelta` but you have to very, very careful with syntax. I think the primary answer is at the bottom though. You say in the title that you want to run this on _theme_ activation but you are using a hook that runs on _plugin_ activation.